# inflating layer-list of shapes in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate, layer-list

I have the following file in my drawable folder called `/drawable/mybkg.xml`. I want to inflate it so I can change the colors programmatically. Is that possible in Android?

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <padding
                android:top="5dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp" />

            <solid
                android:angle="270"
                android:color="#1bd4f6" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#121ce5" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Foreground -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >

            <solid android:color="#1b90f6" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I just now saw a class called  `LayerDrawable`. Does anyone know how I could convert my xml file into such a  `LayerDrawable` either by writing the code or inflating the existing xml?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Resources.getDrawable(int id)` method. Here is the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)
It inflates any kind of drawable resource. The only thing that is left for you to do is to cast the returned drawable to the most specific type that you need (in your case to `LayerDrawable`). Here is an example:

```
// calling from Activity
LayerDrawable d = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
```